# How can I use a transient service within a singleton service?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have some data that I want to persist in memory as it doesn’t change very often so I am planning to use a singleton service

However when the data does change I need to get it from the database which requires a service that is transient

How can I do this because it’s not possible to inject a transient service into a singleton one?

Paul

Comment: You cannot due to the lifetime of the singleton vs the lifetime of the transient service.
Sounds like you have the wrong approach here, if your singleton relies on data from a database, have you looked at different solutions e.g. Caching data in memory for example?

Comment: That’s effectively what I am doing but I need a way of updating that cache

Comment: You can inject transient service to the singleton, but you should be aware that that transient service instance will have same lifetime as singleton it is injected in.

Comment: I get an error if I do that in an azure function it’s still the same issue though in how do I update a cache when my database access is via a transient repository

Comment: Split it out, don't have this singleton service accessing the database, give that responsibility to a different part of the function, then allow external classes to submit updated data to your singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another transient service to use your database and update your cache. let's call it dataProviderService. Then you inject your transient database service and your singletone cache service. something like this

```
public class DataProviderService : IDataProviderService
{
    private readonly ICacheStorage cache;
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public DataProviderService(ICacheSotrage cache, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Something> GetSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (data exist in cache and not expired)
            return cache.GetSomething();

        var items = await dbContext.GetSomething(cancellationToken);
        cache.SetSomething(items);

        return items;
    }
}

services.AddTransient<IDataProviderService, DataProviderService>();
```

Never inject transient service to a singleton service. It just make your code unreliable.

Comment: Hello even if I do this way, I have a problem because my overall service is Singleton, maybe I have to make that service Transient but then I still have an issue in how do I persist the cache?

Comment: In example above ICacheSotrage is your singleton service that has cache data. You can inject singleton service into transient service. @Paul

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean

Comment: But if my main service is a singleton even with this approach where the cached data is held inside a singleton how can I invoke it because DataProviderService is transient